# Besides Etherscan, Are There Other Places to Verify/Publish Contract Code?

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, verify

The title says it, but I also need at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Etherscan is the most cut-and-dry, but there are at least a couple of other resources available:

- [SmartContract.Codes](https://smartcontract.codes/) - a p2p search engine for smart contract source code.
- [ethPM](https://www.ethpm.com/) - a decentralized package manager used to distribute EVM smart contracts and projects.

I'm a big fan of ethPM, but it can take a bit of time to understand. Here are a few more links that might come in useful:

- [Getting started with EthPM & Web3.py](https://snake-charmers.ethereum.org/2019/01/24/ethpm.html) by Nick Gheorghita
- [ethPM Registry Explorer](http://explorer.ethpm.com/)
- [Brownie ethPM Docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ethpm.html)